# I'm trying to copy a string array onto another string array but in reverse

Tags: arrays, c, string

I want to copy a string array onto another string array, but this other string array would be in reverse. (for example: stop becomes pots).

Here is the code that I write:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

char notreversed[] = {};
int i, k, length;


scanf("%s", notreversed);
length = strlen(notreversed);

char reversed[length];

for(i=0; i<length ; i++ ){
    reversed[i] = notreversed[length-i];
  
}
printf("%s", reversed);

}
```

My plan was to use for loop to put in the string from the array one by one, but it always gave me an "exit status 116" error. May I know the reason why?

Comment: As a starter you must do `char reversed[length+1];` to account for the null terminator.

Comment: `char notreversed[] = {};` invalid and meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You must allocate enough space to `notreversed` to store your string read.
- `length-i` should be `length-1-i`.
- Terminating null-character must be added to `reversed` before printing via `%s`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){

    char notreversed[102401] = {}; /* allocating 100KiB, hoping this is enough... */
    int i, k, length;


    scanf("%102400s", notreversed); /* add size limit to avoid buffer overrun */
    length = strlen(notreversed);

    char reversed[length+1]; /* +1 for terminating null-character */

    for(i=0; i<length ; i++ ){
        reversed[i] = notreversed[length-1-i]; /* fix index */
      
    }
    reversed[length] = '\0'; /* add terminating null-character */
    printf("%s", reversed);

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I forgot about the terminating null-character and never had the idea to allocate size limit to the string.